# How to open a new tab in the server command line?

Tags: command-line, server

What are the keyboard shortcuts to manipulate tabs (open new tab, navigate between tabs ...) in the command line of ubuntu server 12.04?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For doing command line work in general I would recommend using `screen`, `tmux` or other of these sort, but to get started, try out `byobu`:

[image]

Default key bindings:

- <kbd>F2</kbd> create a tab
- <kbd>F3</kbd> & <kbd>F4</kbd> you can move around back and forth
- <kbd>F6</kbd> detach session. Resume later - very powerful!
- <kbd>F7</kbd> copy mode - allows you to scroll using arrow keys and search for keywords
- <kbd>F8</kbd> rename window
- <kbd>F9</kbd> Menu & help (more key bindings and features here!)
- type `exit`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to exit regularly one shell/window.

Byobu works regardless the type of connection to your server. This works in regular terminals (also desktops), Virtual Terminals, serial TTYs, SSH sessions, etc.

Comment: And for those SSHing to a Linux terminal using Byobu on a Mac, you may need to hit `Fn` + the keybindings presented by @gertvdijik. Took me a while to figure this out...

Comment: @bafromca Well, that's how function keys on your hardware works. I'm assuming in my answer the user is fimiliar on how to send a function keys on your keyboard. If not, then that's a totally different question imo. (If my keyboard would require me to use Fn + F1 key to send F1, I would throw it out of the window, really).

Comment: The `F` keys are very rarely used on Macs, so for F-centric OSes like Linux, it's helpful for Mac users to know they are require to hit the `Fn` key to activate `F2`. It wasn't that your answer was incorrect, it was an addition for Mac users SSHing in to a Linux machine using Byobu.

Comment: @bafromca Really? I mean, I use it all the time in Ubuntu. Or do you mean those keys are rarely used on OS X?

Comment: F-keys are rarely used on OS X. Sorry, I was just adding my 2 cents as a Mac dev who SSHes into Ubuntu servers often.

Answer (score 2):

You will need GNU-Screen (`sudo apt-get install screen`) or you install byobu (a wrapper, that brings GNU-Screen too). From now on you have the possibility to have multiple "windows" in one virtual terminal.
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>  <kbd>c</kbd> will create another "window"
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>  <kbd>n</kbd> will switch to the next one
Of course byobu makes it more comfortable :-)

Comment: "byobu (a wrapper, that brings GNU-Screen too)" Actually, it seems that Ubuntu 12.04 ships with Byobu using `tmux` instead. On Debian Squeeze it's still using Screen. Byobu is versatile and can be configured to use either of the two.